# How to join on one table if value is not null else join to a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract geographic information from a table which often has granular geographic information which we would like to aggregate up to the state or country level. However, there are often null values in the 'State' field before assigning it our own mapping based on a code value. If there are null values in the state column e.g. `geo.AreaGeographySID = Null`, I want to join on the `Country` column `geo.CountryGeographySID`. This value then forms part of a second join clause as shown in my unsuccessful attempt below

My issue is the region extracted from the final `[Reference].[dbo].[region_definitions]` table is already part of a messy case when statement in the select clause, meaning I don't really want to add another case statement there, I would ideal want to do it at the join stage but I am not sure how to achieve this!

```
case 
    when y.Code IN (23,27,30,41,60,61,68) then r.aMapping
    when y.Code IN (11,12,13,14,15,18,31,33,51,52,53,54,55,58,70,72,76) then r.bMapping
    when y.Code IN (20,43,44) then r.cMapping
    When y.Code IN (5,6)  then r.dMapping
    else Concat ('e-',r.eMapping)
end as Region

into #table1
from #table0 as y
left join 
    [Geography].[dbo].[tGeography] as geo on y.GeographySID = geo.GeographySID 
left join 
    [Reference].[dbo].[region_definitions] as r on 
        case geo.AreaGeographySID <> NULL
            then geo.AreaGeographySID = r.GeographySID AND
            else r.GeographySID AND geo.AreaGeographySID = NULL
        end
```

Comment: I don't think can do what you want. Build a query that calculates a field: `IIf(AreaGeographySID IS NULL, CountryGeographySID, AreaGeographySID) AS Locale`. Then build another query using the first that joins to Locale field.

Comment: `... r ON r.GeographySID = COALESCE(geo.AreaGeographySID, geo.CountryGeographySID)`?